# How to perform a DB cleanup operation upon shutdown in an EJB container

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I have an EJB app. which basically has to execute a SQL query when it is shutdown. A shutdown hook would presumably work, but that way I can't use injected entitymanager/datasource etc.

Is there a way to provide a shutdown hook that can invoke methods on EJB bean?

Our EJB container is JBoss5.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this works:
(EDIT: For some reason the previously posted answer did not work with JBoss5.1. This works.)

```
    public class SomeServlet extends GenericServlet {
        public void destroy(){
            InitialContext ctx = null;
            try{
                ctx = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:/someDataSource");
                doStuff();
            }catch(Exception e){
                log.error("Bad things happened",e);
            }

            finally{
                try {
                    ctx.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }//destroy()
    }//class
```

Answer (score 0):

for ejbs the approach would be same as what zwei has mentioned, but to add an initializaiton or cleanup ejb with a method having annotation **PreDestroy**